# Count a calculated field

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

Using SQL Server 2012.

I have the following code:

```
Select Distinct [A_number] + '-' + convert(varchar(10),[zone]) As myNumber
FROM [dbo].[soils];
```

I need to edit this query to give me a count of each `myNumber`.
Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is use a `group by` statement:

```
SELECT A_number,
    zone,
    COUNT(*) AS c
FROM dbo.soils
GROUP BY A_number,
    zone;
```

Then, use that result to concat your fields. Doing it that way will allow for the use of indexs:

```
WITH numbers AS (
   SELECT A_number,
        zone,
        COUNT(*) AS c
    FROM dbo.soils
    GROUP BY A_number,
        zone
)
SELECT A_number + '-' + convert(varchar(10),zone) As myNumber,
    c AS number_count
FROM numbers;
```

Comment: Doing the group by operation on bare columns is the normative pattern.  That allows a suitable index to be used. With no WHERE clause, the best bet for an optimal index for this query would have leading columns of `(A_number,zone)`. +10. There is an edge case where this query would return a different result from the original. Consider rows with `(A_number,zone)` values of `('1-','a')` and `('1','-a')`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `COUNT()`

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT [A_number]  + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),[zone]))
FROM [dbo].[soils]
```

which will give you a count on unique `myNumber` from the conversion.

And Consider `GROUP BY` if you need a count of each unique mynumber.

```
SELECT [A_number]  + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),[zone]), COUNT(*)
FROM [dbo].[soils]
GROUP BY [A_number]  + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),[zone])
```

Comment: Thanks but I need a count of each unique mynumber not the total number of unique mynumber

Comment: Consider 'GROUP BY`

Answer (score 0):

To get a count of rows associated with each value of `myNumber`, ditch the `DISTINCT` and use a `GROUP BY` instead.

Most straightforward example, repeat the expression in the SELECT list in the GROUP BY clause:

```
SELECT [A_number] + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),[zone]) AS myNumber
     , COUNT(*) AS cnt
  FROM [dbo].[soils]
 GROUP
    BY [A_number] + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),[zone])
```

For trivial sets, performance won't be a problem. For larger sets, performance can suffer. The solution there is to rework the query to take advantage of existing indexes, or add appropriate indexes.

Comment: @JRLambert: you are right. DOH! Totally missed the `COUNT(*)` aggregate. Fixed now. I also could have chosen to use `SUM(1) AS cnt`